# jQuery parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm reading data from a database and adding it to a table to be displayed on a webpage. The table that this data is added to lies inside a panel. To view this table I would have to use this Javascript to expand the panel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

To see where the class names `flip` and `panel` come from see below:

```
<div class="panel">
    <table>
      ...
    </table>
</div>

<p class="flip" onmouseover="this.style.color='red';this.style.cursor='hand'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';this.style.cursor='pointer'"> VIEW TABLE </p>
```

Now, since I'm reading data from the database iteratively, the number of item in there could be anything.

How do I do this such that each has it's own identity, so that when I click on "VIEW TABLE" then each responds on its own. At the moment when I click on one, all expand and vice-versa, obviously because the share a common class name. I've tried to make sure that the class name be the entry id, but certain things break.

Comment: Please post the code and also explain some more on how things break when you use the entry id as the class name. Don't forget you can use multiple class names and also the id/name attributes to identify page elements.

Comment: SO, are you saying you have a new <div... for each new <p... and that the mouse over (or click) of the <p> should show the cooresponding <div>??

Answer (score 0):

add to the element you want to fire the click event and send a refrence to it for example

the div will have on click event will look like this

```
<div onclick="MyFunction(this);"> </div>
```

in the function body recieve the object then reach to the element you want

```
function MyFunction(sender)
{
  $(sender).//now you have the element and could reach to the parent or the child as you want 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making this assumption: You saying you have a new `<div...` for each new `<p...` and that the mouse over (or click) of the `<p>` should show the cooresponding `<div>`.

Try using this: for cooresponding instances.

```
$('.flip').click(function()
{
   $('.panel').eq($(this).index()).slideToggle("slow"); 
});
```

Comment: I think you have an extra set of parenthesis in there. Should be `$('.flip').click(function() { /* ... */ })`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) for your layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $(".flip").live("click", function(){
   $(this).prev(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
 });
</script>
```

This will select the previous `class="panel"` to the `class="flip"` you clicked and slideToggle it.  Also, since you may have any number of these handlers that will be the same, I suggest you use `.live()` like my example above, using 1 event handler instead of `n` event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign a new id for each 'panel' based on something in the db, or just with a sequential number? If so, then you could try this:

```
<div class="panel" id="panel_1"> 
  <table> 
    ... 
  </table> 
</div> 

<p class="flip" onClick="$(".panel_1").slideToggle("slow");    " ... >

<div class="panel" id="panel_2"> 
</div> 

<p class="flip" onClick="$(".panel_2").slideToggle("slow");    " ... >
```

etc.